# How to use suspend function on Room Db?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Room Db using coroutines in kotlin. This is my Dao interface:

```
@Dao
interface CheckListNameDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertName(name: CheckListName)


    @Query("SELECT * FROM CheckListNamesTable")
    fun getAllNames(): LiveData<List<CheckListName>>
}
```

`getAllNames()` method works fine. The problem is with the `insertName()` method. When I remove the `suspend` keyword from the `insertName()` method, it throws this exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`
But, when I use `suspend` keyword, I cannot build the project anymore. It shows the following error:

```
error: Methods annotated with @Insert can return either void, long, Long, long[], Long[] or List<Long>.
public abstract java.lang.Object insertName(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Why this error is showing? My code is based on this [Android Room with a View - Kotlin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#8)

**Edit:** 
This is my repository:

```
class MainRepository(application: Application) {

        private var nameDao: CheckListNameDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application.applicationContext)
                .checkListNameDao()

        fun getAllNames(): LiveData<List<CheckListName>> {
            return nameDao.getAllNames()
        }

        suspend fun setNewListName(checkListName: CheckListName) {
            nameDao.insertName(checkListName)
        }
    }
```

This is the viewmodel:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var mainRepository = MainRepository(application)

    fun getAllNames(): LiveData<List<CheckListName>> {
        return mainRepository.getAllNames()
    }

    fun setNewListName(name: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mainRepository.setNewListName(CheckListName(0, name))
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I am also getting this error when I add the `suspend` keyword:

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> p1);
```

This is the `CheckListName` data class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "CheckListNamesTable")
data class CheckListName(

        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Int,

        var name: String
)
```

Comment: Can you share the code from where you have call insertName method?

Comment: @KishanMaurya i have added repository and view model classes

Comment: As per error, the insert should have a return type.
@Insert
 suspend fun insertName(name: CheckListName):Long

now handle this in viewmodel

Comment: @KishanMaurya I have added a `Long` return type  and the error still shows up.

Comment: @KishanMaurya  i  have edited the question again.

Comment: share the code link. Let me debug from my end.

Comment: may we need to add conflict code like: @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)

Answer (score 8):

As per the [Room Declaring Dependencies documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies), you need a dependency on `room-ktx` to use Coroutines and, with that, `suspend` methods:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.3"
```

Comment: What version of Room are you using?

Comment: i am using version  2.2.3

Answer (score 5):

Edit: Your code is correct it's can be used for room database with suspend function. Just edit your Gradle dependencies like bellow to fixed that error.

If you using kotlin version (**1.7.0**) shoud work with room latest alpha version (**2.5.0-alpha02**)

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0-alpha02"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-alpha02"
```

If you want using room in stable version (**2.4.2**) should work with kotlin version (**1.6.20**)

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.20"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
```

I have tried both and they work. this is the reference: [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236612358)

Comment: This doesn't answers the question. The OP has asked how to use suspend function. But what you have written is the dependencies required for room database. Please edi it.

Comment: Oh ya sorry, thank to remind me. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet contains a sample database configuration with one entity and one DAO:

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val CheckListName: String?,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The suspend does not work in Room DAO with the quires that return LiveData and with the higher Kotlin version than: 1.4.32

More please see here: [Link](https://androidwithdivya.wordpress.com/2021/07/01/room-error-type-of-the-parameter-must-be-a-class-annotated-with-entity-or-a-collection-array-of-it/)

Answer (score 0):

For me changing from `kapt` to `ksp` worked, so, replace

```
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
```

to

```
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
```

Answer (score -1):

Only change to your fun to this :

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)

suspend fun insertName(name: CheckListName) : Long
```

Comment: Please, check if the solution you offer has already been posted before posting.